# Is there a way to avoid the 301 "Moved Permanently" response when using a greedy path paremeter(proxy)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I'd like to be able to just drop the greedy path parameter "{proxy+}" and redirect to an existing api endpoint.

ie, if a user attempts to access `www.my-website.com/api/a/b/c/d...`, I'd like to simply return the response `www.my-website.com/api/a` would give.

So I configured API Gateway to redirect

`blahblah.execute-api.region.amazonaws/com/stage/a/{proxy+}`

to

`blahblah.execute-api.region.amazonaws/com/stage/a`

via HTTP proxy. But when trying to curl my way through to test it, I just get a "301 moved permanently" response.

How do I skip this step and return the target's response directly?

Comment: possible duplicate. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34345127/rewrite-destination-path-in-api-gateway-integration-request

Comment: @GarrGodfrey A path parameter {a} and a greedy path parameter {a+} are inherently different in the API Gateway, as the latter forces the resource into proxy mode.

Comment: @GibberlingLard *"So I configured API Gateway to redirect ... via HTTP proxy"*.  You need to explain what that actually means, because it doesn't seem obvious... via http proxy back to itself?  In that case, that's a strange and inefficient solution, but it shouldn't return a 301.  Perhaps capturing the request and response header and showing them would clarify this.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot when configuring an '{parameter+}' type endpoint, there are only two options available - Lambda Proxy and HTTP proxy. I'm not sure how I'd clarify this further - I'm redirecting 'mysite.com/blahblahblah' to 'mysite.com', ie back to a parent point.

Comment: Redirecting, in HTTP, means a specific thing -- a 30X response.  Instead, it sounds like you're describing looping the API back onto itself... which could create quite a mess if it were allowed to indefinitely cascade, so API Gateway may be protecting itself from sending requests from its back-side, back around to its front side.