# Is Socket.io compatible with AWS Api Gateway yet?

Tags: amazon-web-services, socket.io, aws-api-gateway

My original question was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70649284/aws-api-gateway-restful-api-socket-io-complains-about-error-route-socket-i), where I was trying to do

`socket.io-client --> AWS Api Gateway Restful API --> socket.io(node.js / Express)`

but I keep getting the `404` error:
`Error: Route '/socket.io?EIO=4&t=xxx&transport=polling' does not exist.`

I found this discussion: https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client/issues/1370 and it seems that `Socket.io` connections from the frontend are not supported by AWS Gateway API.

It seems to be that nobody was successful in connecting socket.io server via AWS API Gateway.

So, the fundamental question is: Is Socket.io compatible with AWS Api Gateway at all?

Answer (score 1):

socket.io is not compatible with AWS socket gw as per the answer from AWS support.