# AWS API and Mapping URLs

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I am looking to setup an API Gateway in front off some services that I have running on Fargate.

All is setup in terms of the VPC Link, the cluster and the services deployed with a private load balancer sitting in front of the services.

I need to now figure out how to map the context path to be something different before it hits the fargate services.

My client wants a context path of /EmailServices but the app on Fargate is running with a context path of /app.

I do not have access to update the app context path and was hoping I could do some magic in API Gateway.

Has anyone done anything like this using Parameter Mapping in API Gateway or is any other approach recommended??

Comment: Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34345127/rewrite-destination-path-in-api-gateway-integration-request) as it looks close to what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@stdunbar provided a link to the correct answer
The details at the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77577527/11612) worked for me